# Get column name in SQL server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query like this

```
Select * from Customers where CustId = 100
```

Is there a way to get a specific column name if I pass the column position in the select list.

So if Column 2 is FirstName, I should be able to get

```
Select *, column[2].Name from Customers Where CustID = 100
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. And it does sound like a really, really strange thing to do. A relational database is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Columns, even while technically having an ordinal position, are always referenced by name. This is not to be confused with referring to fields within a SELECT list by their ordinal position within an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I am trying to process data that I imported from a spreadsheet to SQL server table. The column names in the spreadsheet need to be row fields unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass? Just number 2? And replace it with Name if name is the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I understand what you are doing, but maybe this sort of thing will help.

```
Select *
      ,(select c.name
          from sys.columns c
               inner join 
               sys.objects o on c.object_id=o.object_id
         where o.name = 'Customers'
           and column_id = 2) column_name
  from Customers 
 where CustID = 100
```

Or if it easier witha variable:

```
declare @column_name SYSNAME

select @column_name = c.name
  from sys.columns c
       inner join 
       sys.objects o on c.object_id=o.object_id
 where o.name = 'Customers'
   and column_id = 2

select *
      ,@column_name 
  from Customers 
 where CustID = 100
```